# Mongoose delete all referenced comments with post

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is my post schema. Which contain a collection of referenced comments.

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }]
});
const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

Here is my comment schema.

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String
});
const Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

Here is my code to delete a post.

```
Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, err => {
    if (!err) {
        res.redirect("/posts");
    } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("back");
    }
});
```

Now i want to delete all those comments referenced to this post. Now how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use `deleteMany` with the `$in` operator.

```js
const deleted = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

await Comment.deleteMany({_id: {$in: deleted.comments}});
```